# Debounce calculation

Tags: embedded

Controller reading two different position signals on CAN at every 20ms, to confirm position need to take 5 samples. Overall debounce time 100ms. How to calculate position when all 5 values are a little bit varied. Is there any logic to handle this kind of scenario.

ex:  values are  5 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4 then the average is 5.2,  it's not a good method because already it is crossed position 5.4

Pls, suggest on this one.

Comment: If you have CAN, then you have a MCU. Why isn't the debouncing de-centralized inside the sensor MCU? And why exactly isn't (moving) average a good method? What do you mean with "crossed position 5.4"? Position of what?

Comment: "debounce" is not the correct term here.  "signal processing", "signal conditioning" or "filtering" are probably more appropriate.  Although given the non-deterministic nature of CAN communications the term "signal" is probably inaccurate too - for that you'd need to be sampling at an accurately deterministic period.

Comment: Your question as it stands is unanswerable, and the requirements are unclear. If this variation is caused by sensor noise rather then real position, then the mean value is reasonable, though a moving-average would be more appropriate.  If the positions are real and the position sensed is genuinely shifting, then you have to ask yourself whether the application should operate on *mean position* or whether in fact the min/max position are relevant.

Comment: Also you need to ask yourself whether the bandwidth of the sensor or the system being sensed is truly as high as 25Hz which is what your sample rate would suggest.

Comment: If position "overshoot" or transients are really critical, then you don't really want to "debounce" in any case.  Perhaps you measure mean, min, max and the code uses whatever measure is appropriate for what it is trying to do. However I am not convinced you really understand the requirements yourself.

Comment: @Clifford CAN is very much deterministic, if done correctly. For example, one trick is to have one node on the bus providing a high priority sync message, When a node receives that one, it should perform the value change. You can get microsecond real-time accuracy this way, if compensating for transmission time and interrupt latency on the receiver-side.

Comment: @lundin : Indeed, but there are many ways this sampling might be done by the unwary that render the samples aperidoc or cause jitter.  So caution required - that's all.  At this frequency it is certainly do-able.